# Google Colab: Retrieve a previous runtime

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I had a power outage that terminated an instance of Google Colab prior to its completion / prior to the generation of the .CSV file that was my intended output. I am pretty sure that the script I ran was able to generate a pandas dataframe prior to termination.

Is there any way in Google Colab to retrieve previous runtimes that have since been closed (i.e. the browser tabs have been closed)? I have tried to go to Manage Sessions, go back through the history of executed commands, etc., which is limited to the new runtime I deployed. I am able to retrieve the version of the script that I want, but not the history of the actual runtime.

Specifically, I am looking to retrieve the pandas dataframe that would have given me the .CSV had the termination not occurred.

Comment: I don't think those variables are persistent

Comment: Thanks, @Chrispresso! That's what I've gotten from a few folks now.